# Titan - the flammable liquid methane moon

Tags: space, space-constructs, space-travel

Would the moon Titan explode if someone were to take a flame to the liquid methane satellite?

Would it explode, implode, simply just pop, or maybe nothing at all due to the freezing temperatures caused by the great distance from our sun.

Thank you for your time guys.

Comment: Actually, this exact question was asked just a month ago on [space.se] as [How could a hot lander enter Titan's atmosphere without setting its hydrocarbons ablaze?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/14359/415) I strongly recommend you read that one.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Robert. Please note that the Worldbuilding Exchange is dedicated to the creation and expansion of fictional worlds/universes, rather than our real one. As such, this question does not fit the site's purpose and is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Downvoted for two reasons: _1)_ Asked on the wrong **SE** site; it would belong to **Astronomy SE** or **Physics SE**. 2) For asking a question a _4th grader in elementary school_ could answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I wanted to tag it as 'PONDERING BRITISH ROYAL MARINES  COMMANDO'  but I just pressed what popped up.. if you could tell me exactly what one to use I'd be very grateful

Comment: @mg30rg As I linked in my previous comment, the question already exists, answered, and is reasonably well received, on Space Exploration.

Answer (score 6):

### No, it would not ignite/explode

Combustion requires:

1. Fuel
2. Oxidizer
3. Ignition source.

#### Fuel

[Titan has Nitrogen + methane atmosphere and is covered with "lakes" of ethane (with dissolved methane and other hydrocarbons).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_%28moon%29#Atmosphere)  The "ground" on Titan is most likely "dirty" water ice.  Water ice on Titan would be like granite on Earth (hard and hundreds of degrees below its melting point).

This means that Titan's surface is covered with fuel.

#### Ignition Source

You propose to introduce an ignition source, so that's also covered.

#### Oxidizer

However, there's no oxidizer on Titan's surface.  At least, there isn't one that's both powerful enough and abundant enough to cause a sustained reaction.

The Earth's atmosphere is 20% oxygen which is the second most powerful oxidizer on the Periodic Table - which is why hydrocarbons burn so easily in our atmosphere.

#### Other Stuff

If your reaction is exothermic enough, then this last issue won't matter.  However, you may have noticed that fires burn better when it is warmer outside.  This is because molecules interact more energetically at higher temperatures.

Titan is ***COLD*** (-180 C)!

Even with the three basic elements required to sustain a combustion reaction, you might not get a vigorous reaction.  This is simply because at those cold temperatures the molecules don't bump into each other very often.

Comment: That was one of my thoughts, however a little part of me wants it to go up, I'm not a giant scale arsonist but I just really loved the idea of a spark or flame of some sort just igniting it... thank you for your answer It's very informative, just not what I wanted to hear.. it brought me a little comfort for some reason thinking of a possible flaming moon.

Comment: I think you could stress the point about temperature even more. The reactions between chemicals depend heavily on their temperature (and phase). I doubt you could even start a hydrocarbon+oxygen reaction at -180°C, as their flash point tends to be way higher: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_point

Comment: Using FOOF as an oxidizer would do the trick even at that temperature. Of course making FOOF is probably far more dangerous than igniting Titan....

Comment: Like NASA'S nuclear explosion outside Jupiter's atmosphere. What if it had flown  the satellite into titan?

Comment: NASA had no nuclear explosions outside of Jupiter's atmosphere.  NASA (an other agencies) did observe about 25 pieces of a comet strike Jupiter.  But NASA had no part in that event other than spectator, just like the rest of us.

Comment: @Thecydides, I agree.  But even if it didn't *ignite* $O_2 + CH_4$ would still react, it would just do so ***very slowly***.  There are thermodynamically unstable chemicals on Earth (e.g. diamond) that will eventually react and disappear.  It's just sometimes those reactions take thousands of years to complete.